# How can I change the recording audio device of SoX?

Tags: audio, audio-recording, sox

In the title: How can I change the recording audio device of SoX?

I am using MacOS (installed with homebrew).

I am interacting with SoX through a Node.js library called [node-audiorecorder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-audiorecorder) that records sound; let me know if there's a better solution that I should be using for recording audio to a .wav file from a specific input device.

EDIT: Just to be clear, we are NOT talking about recording input from the default input device here.

Comment: it would help if you updated your question with this info ... my laptop is linux so this may not apply to osx however add the username who will be running your code to group audio `sudo usermod -aG audio $USER` then reboot ... in a terminal issue `arecord -l `  to list out all available audio devices ... arecord is an alsa utility ... does that list show the alternative audio device you are interested in ?  beautiful thing about `sox` is it can also be executed directly on the terminal ... once you have it doing your bidding from a terminal then you know the nodejs will be able to do it too

Comment: I can't use `arecord` on macos. Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 2):

There is an device option in the constructor.

```js
const AudioRecorder = require('node-audiorecorder');


const options = {
  program: `sox`,
  device: null, // Recording device you want to use.

};

let audioRecorder = new AudioRecorder(options);
```

Comment: When I try to use this method of attaching a device, in the .wav file, it outputs the exact same output you could get by running `man sox`.

Comment: When I set the "device" property in the options, and I specify the output, the output wav file's content is equal to the content in the man page of sox, yes. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: How are you specifying the output? Mind sharing your code?

Comment: Looks like the module was written wrong: https://github.com/RedKenrok/node-audiorecorder/issues/18#issuecomment-583774916
A different command has to be run to specify the device